# Javascript Object Iteration with for loop

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, hashtable

I am trying to count how many time the unique characters appears in a string.
but I am stuck at the object iteration where the it only returns 1 no matter how many times same character appears more than one time:

```js
function allUniqueCha(word) {
  var wordObj = {};
  var wordArray = word.split([, ]);
  wordArray.forEach(function(c) {
    wordObj[c] = +1;
  });
  console.log(wordArray);
  console.log(wordObj);
}

allUniqueCha("Bubble")
```

The output is : {B:1, u:1,b:1,l:1,e:1} but the expected value of key "b" should be 2.

Comment: What is the initial value of `wordObj[c]`? What happens when you assign `+1` to it?

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

```
 wordObj[c]=+1;
```

With some formatting:

```
 wordObj[c] = +1;
```

You always assign `+1` to the value, there is no increment here. Try

```
 wordObj[c] = (wordObj[c] || 0)+1;
```

And

```
var wordArray = word.split([, ]);
```

should be rather

```
var wordArray = word.split("");
```

```js
function allUniqueCha(word) {
  var wordObj = {};
  var wordArray = word.split("");
  wordArray.forEach(function(c) {
    wordObj[c] = (wordObj[c] || 0) +1;
  });
  console.log(wordArray);
  console.log(wordObj);
}

allUniqueCha("Bubble")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
wordObj[c] = +1;
```

you are assigning the value `+1` to the property. What you want to do is increment the value by 1, so:

```
wordObj[c] += 1;
```

However, initially `wordObj[c]` doesn't exist so you're trying to increment *undefined*, which will throw an error. So yo must test if the property exists and if not, create it an initialise it.

```js
function allUniqueCha(word) {
  var wordObj = {};
  var wordArray = word.split([, ]);
  wordArray.forEach(function(c) {
    if (!wordObj.hasOwnProperty(c)){
      wordObj[c] = 0;
    }
    wordObj[c] += 1;
  });
  console.log(wordArray);
  console.log(wordObj);
}

allUniqueCha("Bubble")
```

You could also use *reduce*:

```js
function allUniqueCha(word) {
  return word.split('').reduce(function(acc, c) {
    acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  },{});
}

console.log(allUniqueCha("Bubble"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This piggy backs on the train of thought in your initial post.   Here is one way to solve the problem you are looking for.

```
function allUniqueCha(word){
  let wordArray = word.split([,]);
  return wordArray.reduce((result, element) => {
    result[element] = result[element] + 1 || 1;
    return result;
  }, {})
}
```